# How do I capture desktop screen image in Windows UWP app?

Tags: windows, uwp, screen, desktop, capture

I am writing windows UWP app, I used PickSingleItemAsync to select the screen to capture. It does not list desktop image. So, How do I capture desktop screen image in Windows UWP app?

Comment: GraphicsCaptureItem can capture an entire screen, or it can capture an app window. The desktop wallpaper doesn't fall into either category.

Answer (score 0):

> I used PickSingleItemAsync to select the screen to capture. It does not list desktop image.

[PickSingleItemAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture.graphicscapturepicker.picksingleitemasync?view=winrt-20348#Windows_Graphics_Capture_GraphicsCapturePicker_PickSingleItemAsync) can use to select current available display then to get desktop screen image.

Open picker -> change select option like following.

[image]

Comment: Yes it works for other windows. But it doesnot display desktop screen (shell window).

Comment: Shell window? what's the shell window?